# How to use OAuth2 and Passport.js for a MEAN (Angular 2+) Application

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, passport.js, mean-stack

I’m trying to apply OAuth2 to an angular 4, MEAN stack application. I am trying to do the authentication using Passport.js and the Google Strategy.

I’ve found a few tutorials, but the difference in stacks has made the tutorials difficult to follow. In case it's relevant the one I am currently following is 'Securing Your Application with OAuth and Passport' found on pluralsight.

So far I configured passport on the server side.

After the configuration, I applied the following to /server/routes.ts:

```
// Should redirect to main page if not authenticated
  router.route.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
      console.log('err');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    next();
  });
  // Authentication
  router.route('/google/callback')
    .get(passport.authenticate('google', {
      successRedirect: '/home/', // was users
      failure: '/error/'
    }));
  router.route('/google/')
    .get(passport.authenticate('google', {
      // Tell Google what we want
      scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
    }));
```

These changes are not pushed to my repo, but the set up of everything can be found [here](https://github.com/cerberus-org/cerberus-app).

The issue I am having with this tutorial is that the client and server do not seem to be separated in the tutorial.

Questions/Thoughts:

1. server/routes contains my api routes, not my paths to my site so it doesn't seem right that the code above would be in server/routes.
2. Also, I cannot write `<a href="/google/"></a>` on my front end because my front end has it's own router and will not look at server/routes for paths.
3. Lastly, I cannot call say

   `.get(passport.authenticate('google', {
             // Tell Google what we want
             scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
               'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']`

in a front end service because then I would have to configure passport on the front end and I believe passport should be configured on the backend since it is supported by the express framework.

If I am on the completely wrong path any guidance on where I can implement OAuth2, on a MEAN (Angular 2+) application using Passport.js would be appreciated.